# how do i change the price feed token from eth /usd to busd/usd with the chainlink oracle?

Tags: solidity, remix, oracles, chainlink

I am trying to get the price feed for BUSD/USD using the chainlink pricefeed oracle but it tells me that the code was reverted. this is also happening when i switch to any other token, i am using the kovan test net

this is the error i get

> call to PriceConsumerV3.getLatestPrice call to PriceConsumerV3.getLatestPrice errored: VM execution error. Reverted 0x

and this is my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

/**
 * Network: Kovan
 * Aggregator: ETH/USD
 * Address: 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
 */
constructor() public {
    priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xcBb98864Ef56E9042e7d2efef76141f15731B82f);
}

/**
 * Returns the latest price
 */
function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
    (
        uint80 roundID, 
        int price,
        uint startedAt,
        uint timeStamp,
        uint80 answeredInRound
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return price;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get BUSD/USD via a price feed on Kovan testnet, [it is not available on that specific network](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/#Kovan%20Testnet). It is [available on Ethereum mainnet](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/#Ethereum%20Mainnet) however.

If you are testing using the price feed, you can always use a mock contract to mock the behavior of the feeds for testing purposes only.